# Python project folder and its Miniconda2 environment folder

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am a beginner trying to learn a bit of Python; first practical applications will be data analytics. My learning setup consists of Mac OS X, Miniconda2, Pycharm and Git.

Is it better to set up a project folder 'bar' within a conda environment folder 'foo' (~/miniconda2/env/foo/bar)?

Or is it better to leave the conda environment alone as ~/miniconda2/env/foo and set up a project folder as ~/repos/bar?

Virtualenv users I've seen put the env and the project in a single folder, but I have not seen a similar, popular or recommended workflow for conda.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I haven't used *conda* myself, I expect they aren't trying to change the concept of a virtual environment too much. That being said, I personally find it better to keep them separate, i.e. have a `~/.virtualenvs` and a `~/repos` folder.

As you mentioned, though, it's pretty common to store both the virtualenv and the project itself in the same folder. What I would stress here is that the virtualenv should then be in the project folder, not the other way around. For example:
`~/repos/Foo/.fooenv`

The reason for this is that virtualenvs should be *disposable*, whereas your *projects* are not. That means that you should be able to freely remove a virtualenv without fearing you've accidentally deleted your project folder along with it.

Comment: Thank you! I think, by default, conda sees only environments within the `/miniconda2/env` directory, so keeping an environment and project files separate makes a lot of sense.